# Transferring UIImage from one class to another

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to take a `UIImage` from one class (pulled from a server) and use it in a separate class (different View Controller).

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

This is my current code in the `SecondViewController`. How can I get it so that I can use the UIImage `image` in my FirstViewController? Thanks!

Comment: How are the two view controllers related?

Comment: Use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/1679187

Comment: @nhgrif They are related by being in the same app I suppose?

Comment: Lemme guess -- pass a pointer to it to the other controller?

Comment: Try using NSNotification and passing the image as the object

Comment: See this section of my book on how to arrange for two instances to see each other: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_visibility_by_instantiation And this section on how to pass data when one vc instantiates another vc: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_presented_view_controller

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple... Try `NSUserDefaults` concept here. You can get UIImage in any view controller of the app if once stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

**Step 1: For Storing**

Image Save on NSUserDefaults in second view controller

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"image"];
```

**Step 2: For Retrieving**

Image retrieve on NSUserDefaults in first view controller:

```
NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: While this works, NSUserDefaults should not be used in this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .xib to navigate from one `ViewController` to another then this code might help you.

Suppose you have image in you `FirstViewController`

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

//------Time to go at another Class lets call it secondViewController

secondViewController *secondview =[[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil WithImage:image];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondview animated:YES];
```

SecondViewController.h

```
@interface secondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong)UIImage *imagefromServer;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil WithImage:(UIImage *)image;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil WithImage:(UIImage *)image
  {
       self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
       if (self) {
       // Custom initialization
       imagefromServer= image;
       }
   return self;
  }
```

Hope helps you